# How to put a database in the project? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have the local database in SQL Server 2014 with four tables volume 1.5 GB. The essence of the program to look for in the database records with the user defines criteria. The program is written and it works fine. We should make sure that the program worked and other users who have not installed the server. How to implement this? Was a idea to serialize the data, but as I understand, it is necessary to deserialize all the data and then look for the right record.

Comment: Have you tried using Sql Express? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx
Have you tried serializing the data to a file and then loading it back in?

Comment: Beyond Ian's suggestion, you could expose the SQL server on your LAN. This has significant concerns as it runs into authentication/security concerns, so a step up would be to protect he database but still expose it via a Web API. I'm not sure what else to do when you have 1.5 GB of information you want to expose.

Comment: I think with the object serialization can solve the problem, but then I have to, every time when the program starts,  deserialize all objects (1.5 GB), only then  do search...

Comment: Deserializating all your data is like moving all your furniture into a truck every day when you leave for work and then moving it back when you get home. Its possible but a bit extreme. If your data is not being changed you can lock down the database by putting it into read only mode.

Comment: @KhorenMansuryan my suggestion was meant to imply that you only load it back into the local SQLExpress database once, either on install or on first run. After that your application runs just like it does on your machine. If you have users who cannot access your SQL Server database (e.g. remote offices) this may be a good approach assuming also, as Ben points out that it's a read-only use of the data. If not, go read up on sync frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments before me already says i think you have 2 options.

Either ship the database with the client (using Sql Express or other similar solutions). That should work fine and will work without a connection to a centralized server but the size of your client package will be quite big. And if you make any changes it will only be locally, but it seems you only make reads to the database from the client?

But if i understand it correctly you install a sql server for each client, since you mention "users who have not installed the server"? Then you already have the problem with a lot of data needing to be sent out to each client, as well as the problem of updating all databases when the data needs to be refreshed.

Another solution is to allow access to the database from the client. This can work in serveral ways, if all your users is in your doman you can handle authentication based on their domain users and skip the authentication part. Then you would only need to send out the client and skip the installation of a big server and all the data.

If they are not on the domain but still on your network you could add a login on your application to allow access to the database or if you trust all your users you could add a read only account and just hardcode the login for that account.

If you want to access the data outside of a trusted environment you should of course add a separate login for each user to allow access and it might even be a good idea to use an api before the database that handles the requests from the client and then does the search to the database in a controlled manner.

I would personally go with using a centralized database to skip all the work of setting up new users and also have a single point to update when the data needs a refresh, but of course it all depends on where your users are.

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
Maybe I incorrectly described the question or problem,
I want to implement this program without server. I want to implement something like the data that come with the program and that it was possible to make search

Comment: Then i would suggest a standalone database like Sqlite or Firebird (there are more of course). Look at this: http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/   Then you dont need to install anything and you still get a database you can run sql against.